# how to solve non linear system that use vector

Tags: python, scipy

I have to solve the following non linear system in which appears matrix term :

```
k1 = self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2) 
k2 = self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
```

in this system self.u[i] is a vector of dimension `n = 1 to 3` so basically it is `self.u[i,j]`

how can I solve using scipy library ? 
I've tried this way but it doesn't works, because when `len(self.u[i]) == 2`
also `k1` and `k2` should have the same dimension this is what i wrote :

```
def equations(variable):
      k1,k2 = variable
      f1 = -k1 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2) 
      f2 = -k2 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
      return np.array([f1,f2]).ravel() #.reshape(2,)  


k1 , k2 = fsolve(equations,(self.u[i],self.u[i]))
```